# TM : Filtering corpus by metadata using wildcard

Tags: filter, metadata, tm

I'm trying to filter a corpus in TM using metadata.
The corpus is called `release_corpus` and has as metadata a field date written in the form of a text such as "1 July 2010". I can select all documents with an exact date using :

```
release_corpus_filter_date <- release_corpus[
meta(release_corpus, tag = "publication") == " 1 July 2010"       
]
```

My question is : how can I select only all documents of the year 2010 for instance. In other words I would like something such as a selection based on `meta(release_corpus, tag = "publication") == string ending with "2010"`

P.S : The object `meta(release_corpus, tag = "publication")`is itself a kind of (strange) list. If I type : `meta(release_corpus, tag = "publication")[1]` it displays `$1 = " 1 July 2010"`

Many thanks for your help !

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?